# Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null

Tags: flutter

/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/material_floating_search_bar-0.3.7/lib/src/util/util.dart:21:18: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.

- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) => callback());
  ^

Answer (score 2):

I believe that's a recent change from `WidgetsBinding?` for that value to a straight `WidgetsBinding`.  Hence, Dart is correctly pointing out that `?.` is no longer needed.